# Android ListView item marquee

Tags: android, xml, listview

Im attempting to marquee items in listview ( which is populated by an ArrayAdapter).

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.tabdemo.Tab2Activity" >

      <ListView
          android:id="@+id/listView1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:fitsSystemWindows="false" 
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:ellipsize="marquee"
          android:marqueeRepeatLimit="1


          >

        </ListView> 

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Can you guys see the issue as its not scrolling and and text is displayed on several lines.

Comment: adapter class and item layout ?

Comment: Is this what  you mean

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/Itemname"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="20sp" 
  android:paddingTop="5dp"
  android:lines="1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
  />
</LinearLayout>

but still not scrolling